# Problem with dual booting Debian on Windows 10

Tags: debian, unetbootin

I don't see an option to boot from my flash drive in advanced startup. 
I tried to download the bootable file from UNetbootin. I selected the distribution option and selected Debian and Stable_NetInstall. Once it's loaded onto my flashdrive I enter advanced startup and I only see the option to start windows 10. Also, I already partitioned my hard drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest looking into whether or not you have the boot from USB option enabled in the BIOS. Also look into whether or not secure boot is enabled, if so disable it before installing. Also make sure that the USB boot option is first priority, or use the boot sequence change function key at boot if your computer has one listed.

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer? @RyanMarr